# Where can I get some information on starting C# programming with MVC / ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm a Java developer looking to learn some C#/ASP.NET.  One thing I've never liked about .NET from the get-go was that it didn't have support for MVC. But now it does!  So I was wondering if anybody knew where to get started learning C# MVC.

Also, do you need the non-free version of developer-studio to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to Will's answer, Scott has a series on ASP.NET MVC development:

[ASP.NET MVC Framework Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 2): URL Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 3): Passing ViewData from Controllers to Views](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC Framework (Part 4): Handling Form Edit and Post Scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx)

Comment: Does anyone know how up-to-date these guides are?  The original aritcles are over a year old.  I would love some <i>written</i> docs like this.

Answer (score 6):

Keep an eye on [Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/Scottgu/)'s and [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/)'s blogs.  They are the primary source of documentation right now.

Be wary, as most posts about MVC are about previous versions and don't apply anymore (anything that uses a lambda is right out, unfortunately).

Of course, you've got a pretty good resource here as well.  Haack occasionally answers questions about MVC...

Comment: I must ask, but why do you say that "anything that uses a lambda is right out"? The lambda functionality is still alive and well in the MVC futures assembly. Or was that what you meant, that the lambda functionality, being in the futures, is in limbo?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/

The Express Edition of [VWD (Visual Web Developer) 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) has support for MVC now.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [A Guide to Learning ASP.NET MVC Beta 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/tags/ASP.NET+MVC/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at a fully functional full featured solution you should check out [TheBeerHouse MVC Project](http://www.codeplex.com/TheBeerHouse/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) I think you will find a lot of really good examples of how to use MVC.

Answer (score 1):

I would check out NerdDinner ASP.NET MVC Tutorial [found here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx)

Comment: I'm working through this right now and it's a great resource for a C#/MVC noob.

Comment: I found that it was a great resource.  It really walks you through all the parts ov the mvc framework along with how to tie things in like security, validation and what not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one, you can browse the meetings list of the local .Net User Group in your area. If you don't see an MVC topic being presented, ask the leader of the group to schedule one. If he can't honor your request, he should still be able to point you to other resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC myself and found [Stephan Walter's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/stephenwalther/archive/tags/ASP.NET+MVC/default.aspx) pretty useful. He has 45 posts with various tips and also posts about two sample ASP.NET MVC sites.

Answer (score 0):

Buy this book,

Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework by Steven Sanderson

It is a very good book.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to start with online tutorials, If you want to learn it systematically, then start with a hard copy book. It will help you to learn things more systematically.